# Passing Expression as an argument

Tags: c#

I am trying to design something like this

```
String name = "John";
Int32 age = 30;

var variable = SomeClass.SomeMethod(Name != "Bob", age > 50)
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
SomeClass.GetName();
SomeClass.GetAge();
SomeClass.IsAgeAboveThreshold();
```

I want `Name != "Bob", age > 50` in this exact format, with possibility of adding more arguments than just those `2`. None of this: `x=>`

How would i go about designing the `SomeClass`?

I did look into `Expressions` and some `Lambda` stuff, but it looks pretty overwhelming, and I don't want to dive into it to deeply before I know that I need it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `x => `?

Comment: Why would you not use LINQ or plain old properties, and what's wrong with a lambda expression? From the sounds of things the way you're approaching whatever problem you're trying to solve is a for real code smell.

Comment: I can use `x = >` or whatever i want within `SomeClass`, but that parameter format needs to be exactly like that, and is out of my control.

Comment: is it that you want to load the predicate from something external - like a user query or configuration file?

Comment: "I want Name != "Bob", age > 50 in this exact format" that is not legal C# syntax, so you'll need to pass it in as a string and build an expression parser.

Comment: Why such strict syntax restrictions that aren't valid in C#?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); you've shown us what you are doing but haven't told us what result you want to get. I know you think you have, but you haven't. For example, do you want “something like this” or does it need to be “in this exact format”. Why is the decision “out of my control”? If there's something controlling what answers are allowed, we need to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you are passing are conditionals.  They return boolean values.  With that in mind, you need to structure the handling methods accordingly:

```
public static string SomeMethod(bool nameTest, bool ageTest)
{
    ...
}
```

Here is a small test exemplifying some basic functionality using this:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String name = "John";
        int age = 30;

        var variable = SomeClass.SomeMethod(name != "bob", age > 50);

        Console.Write(variable);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public static string SomeMethod(bool nameTest, bool ageTest)
        {
            return string.Format("nameTest is {0}, ageTest is {1}", nameTest.ToString(), ageTest.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```